# detect why iOS app went into background, hardware home or incoming push notification

Tags: ios, ios6, nsnotificationcenter

I want my app to behave differently if the user pushes hardware home button, versus other reasons it may go into background.  I think I have sorted out the main cases, except I can't tell the difference between user tapping on incoming push notification from another app and hitting the hardware home.  In iOS 5, I was getting an `applicationWillResignActive` when the notify first appeared, and then `applicationDidEnterBackground` when the user tapped.  In iOS 6, I cannot find any event triggered by the appearance of a banner notification from another app.  The `applicationWillResignActive` and `applicationDidEnterBackground` come back to back, just as in hitting hardware home.  I tried listening to `UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification` and other `UIWindow` notification, but nothing is fired.  Any ideas?

Comment: There is no difference code-wise.  All the information you have is that the app "went into the background".

Comment: agree to @borrrden; as of now there is no way to figure out this.

Comment: Although you can make a pretty good guess when it is alert style notification or by multitasking bar.  In that case you get the resign when it appears.  I guess because the banners disappear so quickly there is no reason to be notified.